# Fail to use let-destruct for tuple in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm a new user for Coq. I have defined some functions:

```
Definition p (a : nat) := (a + 1, a + 2, a + 3).

Definition q :=
let (s, r, t) := p 1 in
s + r + t.

Definition q' :=
match p 1 with
| (s, r, t) => s + r + t
end.
```

I'm trying to destruct the result of p into a tuple representation. However coqc complains on q:

```
Error: Destructing let on this type expects 2 variables.
```

while q' can pass the compilation. If I change p to return a pair(a + 1, a + 2), the corresponding q and q' both work fine.

**Why let-destruct only allows pair? Or have I made any error in syntax?** I've checked with Coq manual but found no clue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What is a bit confusing in Coq is that there are *two* different forms of destructing let. The one you are looking for needs a quote before the pattern:

```
Definition p (a : nat) := (a + 1, a + 2, a + 3).

Definition q :=
  let '(s, r, t) := p 1 in
  s + r + t.
```

Prefixing the pattern with a quote allows you to use nested patterns and use user-defined notations in them. The form without the quote only works with one-level patterns, and doesn't allow you to use notations, or refer to constructor names in your patterns.

Comment: Thank you! So the 3-member tuple should be regarded as destructing again on the first member of pair, then I have to use 'quote'?